# how can I inject nodejs native module to pupppeteer page

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I have a application use with NWjs,in my application pages ,it use many many 
 nodejs native module(like fs/http/etc)

then I want to use puppeteer to test my page,so we need inject nodejs native module to run the page

I try to run below code ,but it doesn't wokred for inject nodejs native module to page

```
const fs = require("fs");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
    await page.exposeFunction("require", function (name) {
        console.log("require module name:"+name);
        return require(name) // or return fs , result is same
    })
    await page.evaluate(async () => {

        const fs = await window.require("fs");
        console.log(fs,typeof fs.readFile);//fs.readFile is undefined

    });
    await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: Did you see the fs object printed in the console atleast?

Comment: Yes , it reutrn a JSHandle@object .  if I return a normal object , it would worked.

Comment: I don't see a `page.goto` in your code sample, what url are you opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok. The problem is that puppeteer only can exchange serializable data with the page context. That is, objects transferable via JSON.stringify.

Functions and other complex Web Api are not transferable. That is why you see a JSHandle@object on page context. It is an object containing all `module.exports` serializable values from `fs` module.

You can make a simple test to see that. Setup in the same folder as your code another file containing a simple module and try to require it in you code. Example:

```js
// file mod1.js
module.exports = {
  number: 1,
  string: 'test',
  object: { complex: 'object' },
  function: function() {}, // this will not be transfered
  fs: require('fs')
};
```

Now you run your code calling this module:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
  await page.exposeFunction("require", function (name) {
    console.log("required module name: " + name);
    return require(name); // or return fs , result is same
  });

  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const module = await window.require("./mod1");
    // changed to JSON.stringify for you to see module's content
    console.log('module:', JSON.stringify(module, null, 2));
  });
  await browser.close();
});
```

Unfortunatly the documentation is not clear in this point about page.exposeFunction method.

EDIT: I came up with a possible solution to require a native module. I've tested only the methods fs.unlikSync, fs.writeFileSync and fs.readFileSync, but they worked. :)  Here is the code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// expose every methods of the moduleName to the Page, under window[moduleName] object.
async function exposeModuleMethods(page, moduleName) {
  const module = require(moduleName);
  const methodsNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(module);
  for (const methodName of methodsNames) {
    await page.exposeFunction('__' + moduleName + '_' + methodName, module[methodName]);
    await page.evaluate((moduleName, methodName) => {
      window[moduleName] = window[moduleName] || {};
      window[moduleName][methodName] = window['__' + moduleName + '_' + methodName]; // alias
    }, moduleName, methodName);
  }
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));

  // expose `require` on Page. When it is used on Page, the function `exposeModuleMethods`
  // expose the individual module's methods on window[moduleName].
  await page.exposeFunction('require', async function (moduleName) {
    await exposeModuleMethods(page, moduleName);
  });

  // make the Page require "fs" native module
  await page.evaluate(async (moduleName) => await require(moduleName), 'fs');

  // make the Page test the "fs" module
  await page.evaluate(async (moduleName) => {
    // save a file on the current directory named "mod2.js"
    await window[moduleName]['writeFileSync']('./mod2.js', 'any text');
    // read the file "mod2.js"
    const mod2 = await window[moduleName]['readFileSync']('./mod2.js', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    // log it's content
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mod2, null, 2));
    // delete the file
    await window[moduleName]['unlinkSync']('./mod2.js');
  }, 'fs');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

today,I finally broken that problem.

solution steps:

1. use nwjs-sdk for puppeteer launch of executeablePath (ps: nw version must than v0.35.4)
2. nwjs-sdk package.json add that cmd args "--enable-features=nw2" (let nwjs launch use chrome native tab page ,because puppeteer need it to use and control)

example code :

```
puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: 'D:/nwjs-sdk-v0.42.2-win-x64/nw.exe',
    ignoreDefaultArgs:true,
    headless:false
}).then(async browser => {
    const res = await  browser.pages();
    const page = res[0];
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        const os = require('os');
        console.log("free memory="+os.freemem()/1024/1024);
    });
})
```